# Javascript enemies follow player

Tags: javascript

I am coding a lil js game for a university project.
I have a 2d map and I can move my player with arrows. Enemies are spawned every 5 seconds and they are guided by the function:

```
enemy.updatePosition = function() {
    if(enemy.isAttacking === false) {           
            var diffX = Math.floor(player.x - enemy.x);
            var diffY = Math.floor(player.y - enemy.y);

            //security distance by player --> superEnemy type 1 uses arrows
            var distance = getDistanceBetweenEntities(player, enemy);
            var gap = 20;


            enemy.pressingRight = diffX > gap;
            enemy.pressingLeft = diffX < -gap;
            enemy.pressingDown = diffY > gap;
            enemy.pressingUp = diffY < -gap;

            enemy.isStopped = false;


                if(enemy.speedX < 0)
                    enemy.speedX = - enemy.speedX;
                if(enemy.speedY < 0)
                    enemy.speedY = - enemy.speedY;
                //bumpers check if hitting a wall or end of map
                var rightBumper = {x:enemy.x + 15, y:enemy.y};
                var leftBumper = {x:enemy.x - 15, y:enemy.y};
                var upBumper = {x:enemy.x, y:enemy.y - 25};
                var downBumper = {x:enemy.x, y:enemy.y + 20};

                if(currentMap.isPositionWall(rightBumper)) {
                    enemy.x -= 1;
                } else {
                    if(enemy.pressingRight)
                        enemy.x += enemy.speedX;
                }
                if(currentMap.isPositionWall(leftBumper)) {
                    enemy.x += 1;
                } else {
                    if(enemy.pressingLeft)
                        enemy.x -= enemy.speedX;
                }

                if(currentMap.isPositionWall(downBumper)) {
                    enemy.y -= 1;
                } else {
                    if(enemy.pressingDown)
                        enemy.y += enemy.speedY;
                }
                if(currentMap.isPositionWall(upBumper)) {
                    enemy.y += 1;
                } else {
                    if(enemy.pressingUp)
                        enemy.y -= enemy.speedY;
                }

                //set position again if the center of the draw 
                //of enemy goes out of map's limits
                if(enemy.x  < enemy.width/2)
                    enemy.x  = enemy.width/2;
                if(enemy.x  > currentMap.width - enemy.width/2)
                    enemy.x  = currentMap.width - enemy.width/2;
                if(enemy.y < enemy.height/2)
                    enemy.y = enemy.height/2;
                if(enemy.y > currentMap.height - enemy.height/2)
                    enemy.y = currentMap.height - enemy.height/2;

        }
    }
}
```

So my enemies follow the player with the values of diffX and diffY. Each enemy has it own speedX and speedY, something like:

```
    var random = 1 + Math.random()*7;   //from 1 to 8
    enemy.speedX = random;
    enemy.speedY = random;
```

The result is that enemies start to overlap, expecially when they are performing an attack(x and y don't changes during attack). Is there a simple way to avoid that without checking a lot of collision? Thanks everyone

Comment: Could you please explain why you need to avoid collision detection?

Comment: My fault. I don't have time to create another collision detection system. I would like to reuse the one which tests collision between two rectangles. I mean I can't create another system right now.

Comment: If you just store the current positions of the ememies you could simply check them for duplicates.

Comment: Thanks creyD. How would you translate them? Do you have an idea on how doing it without having conflicts with game borders?

Comment: I guess @MisterM implemented his solution pretty similar to what I suggested, you should check it out. If you however can not live with collision detection then you should consider that the enemies go different paths all the time to automatically not collide.

Answer (score 1):

There are more options for you, but here is one simple collision detection. 
First you will need to make every `enemy` unique like giving everyone of them a unique name. This doesn't need to be complicated just like enemy1, enemy2, .... enemy223. You can do it at the point where you spawn the enemy, like this:

```
enemy['name'] = 'enemy' + i++;
```

so you can access it like this:

```
enemy.name;
```

Important: you should write some kind position that updates everytime the 'enemy' changes position or every tick.

```
enemy['position'] = enemy.x+','+enemy.y;
```

make an array into that you can write the positions of every `enemy`. I know this is not the best option but it's simple and will work for now.

```
var pstns = [];
```

After that write every enemy into the array (just do it at spawn). I would like to mention that the following is not good practice.

```
var pstnsObj = {};
pstnsObj[enemy.name] = enemy.position;
pstns.push(pstnsObj);
```

Next you need to update the position in the array every tick with every `enemy`. This is only one example you can do it multiple ways or even automate this process.

```
function updatePstns(id, position){
    pstns[id][Object.keys(pstns[id])[0]] = position;
    //just in case:
    return pstns;
}
//updating first enemy:
updatePstns(0, enemy.position);
```

now for the collision:

```
function checkCollision(){
    var count = 0;
    pstns.forEach(function(e){
        for(i=0; i<pstns.length; i++){
            if(pstns[e][Object.keys(pstns[e])[0]] == pstns[i][Object.keys(pstns[i])[0]]){
               count++;
            }
        }
        if(count > 1){
            console.log('enemy ' + pstns[e] + 'collides with ' + count + 'enemies');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks MisterM, I found a solution at the end